# Systemd: How to stop an enabled process if the user start the same application

Tags: systemd

If process is enabled to start on boot, in this specific case it's a headless  qlcplus lighting controller.  Is there a way to stop that process if a user later logs in and manually start the full qlcplus GUI application in order to edit the controller file?

I could write a script that disables the systemd process, before starting the qlcplus gui but I'd need to re-enable the systemd process when the GUI exits. I should mention that this system is to be used by lighting technicians (unfamiliar with linux) not computer tech's, so no typing into a CL terminal is allowed.

I could also have a ~/.config/autostart/qlcplus.desktop, I was just curious if there's a systemd way of doing this and|or ensure there's only ever a single instance running.

This is to unsure that the lighting is always controlled even after unattended|unscheduled reboots.  Running 2 DMX controller threads is obviously a "bad thing".

System is a raspberry pi with raspbian-stretch.

Comment: could you just add a wrapper script to the user application start to determine if the systemd started task is running and if yes then use the running process instead of killing  it or launching a dupe ... this is a pattern I use in similar use cases

Comment: Would the [web interface](http://www.qlcplus.org/docs/webinterface.html) be sufficient for your techs to use? If so, you wouldn't have to touch the running service at all, and only require a browser on the client.